# How to add a circle/dot to a opencv video?

Tags: c++, opencv, video

I have a comma separated values file with x & y coordinates. I need to place a dot/circle over opencv video from camera and track with x y coordinates from comma separated values file. I have code to display camera:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the video camera no. 0

    if (!cap.isOpened())  // if not success, exit program
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the video cam" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    double dWidth = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); //get the width of frames of the video
    double dHeight = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); //get the height of frames of the video

    cout << "Frame size : " << dWidth << " x " << dHeight << endl;

    namedWindow("CameraDisplay",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "CameraDisplay"

    while (1)
    {
        Mat frame;

        bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

        if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
        {
             cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << endl;
             break;
        }

        imshow("CameraDisplay", frame); //show the frame in "CameraDisplay" window

        if (waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
        {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break; 
        }
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? What is your problem with placing the dot/circle? How does your problem relate to the code you provided? Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. Then please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27863543/edit) your post and improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frame captured by your webcam is nothing but a single image. So, you can put a circle at your webcam video in the same manner as you do with your single image.

The following is the openCV method to place a circle at your image:

```
void circle(Mat& img, Point center, int radius, const Scalar& color, int thickness=1, int lineType=8, int shift=0)
```

For example:

```
circle(frame, Point2i(x-coordinate, y-coordinate), 5, Scalar(0,125,230), 4, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got circle on my video from your answer. I have a set of x y coordinates in separate file(example. 300, 200) as csv. I need to move dot/circle based on the x y coordinates in the video captured from camera.

Comment: sorry, i did not understand what do you exactly want when you said "need to move dot/circle based on the xy coordinate in the video". Who's x-y coordinate you are talking about? Do you want to say that you need to read the x-y coordinates from the file and then put the dot/circles at that place???

Comment: Yes. You are right. The dot/cirle will move among the video based on the xy coordinate data from file.

Comment: @innoraj: The procedure of drawing the circle will remain same and you just need to read the coordinates from your data file. You can make a copy your your `frame` inside the `while loop` using `Mat imageCopy = frame.clone()` and then draw the circle/dots over that `imageCopy` and then display it. In this way, you would have a feel as if the circle/dots are moving.

Comment: I couldn't able to extract xy coordinates from file. Still, I tried with simple x=x++; y=y++; the circle is moving over the video.

Comment: if you can't extract from the file then, post a new question at SO about how to extract data from a datafile...actually its not to difficult but you must try yourself.

Comment: @innoraj: please accept the answer if it was helpful to you.